# making a specific section tag 100% width and height of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<section id="first">
  <div>
   <h2>Header</h2>
   <p>Des</p>
   <a href="#second">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="second">
  <div>
   <h2>Header</h2>
   <p>Des</p>
   <a href="#first">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want section#first to be width 100% and height 100% no matter what size the window is and then when the anchor tag is clicked i want section#second to do the same making each section effectively its own page.

Ive tried adding width: 100% and height: 100% to each section but i think js is required to achieve this? can anyone advise me on how this can be achieved?

Kyle

Comment: What do you mean each its own page? If they are both 100% height and width one will overlap the other... or is that the behaviour you want?

Comment: @mrBorna i want #first to take up the whole browser window no matter what size, #second should only be seen when the a tag is selected or the user scrolls

Answer (score 1):

Using `width: 100%;` should effectively keep the div at the width of the window, but the height is a little tricky.

One technique is to use javascript to maintain the height.  Here's an example.

```
function handleResize(){
    $("#first").height($(window).height());
}
```

This will set the height on page load, but as the page is resized it won't update.

To handle the resizing you can bind to the `resize` event.

```
$(window).bind('resize', handleResize);
```

You might also need to consider some other events, for example: `onorientationchange` is an event fired by the iPad when it is rotated.

These code samples use jQuery for simplicity, but it's not required.

To have the two pages alternate, you can do something like:

```
function handleResize(selector){
    $(selector).height($(window).height());
}
function handleShrink(selector){
    $(selector).height(0);
}
$("#pageTwoLink").click(function(){
    handleShrink("#first");
    handleResize("#second");
}
$("#pageOneLink").click(function(){
    handleShrink("#second");
    handleResize("#first");
}
```

Of course, this could be drastically cleaned up, if you provide some more information about the exact specification.

Comment: thanks @idbentley basically i just want to make sure the section tag occupies the full width and height of the browser window and can adapt on resize. i then want to add a scrollto to the anchor tags that will scroll to the next/prev section

Comment: Always exhaust your options with css before you resort to javascript. many browsers(albeit shitty ones) don't have javascript enabled. Besides for this particular solution the entire thing can be done with `section#first:target,section#second:target{width:100%;height:100%;}` which is shorter anyway

Comment: `height:100%` is a particularly persnickity item in css.  There are many many cases in which it won't do what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Great! No javascript required! its like 2 sections of easy css:

```
  section#first{
    background:darkkhaki;
  }
  section#second{
    background:darkseagreen;
  }

  section#first:target,section#second:target{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/emeyag/edit

Comment: @mrBoma section#first doesnt occupy the whole browser window, the 100% height doesnt apply?

Comment: Well you have to put it in a container (for example body) with height 100% percent because it fills 100% of the PARENT CONTAINER; so set the css of you parent container to height:100%; here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/rWuCf/

Answer (score 0):

By setting the position property to fixed, you allow the two sections to exist in the same spot.

```
section{ position:fixed; top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;}
```

Then you can use javascript to change which one is visible:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('section').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```